# Generate PDF having multiple images as individual pages using Android SDK PDFDocument API

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, android-pdf-api

I cannot find any sample as to how one can generate a pdf file made up of individual images as pages using Android SDK's new [PDFDocument API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html)

I am trying to generate a pdf file by picking up images from an arraylist of image file names and then loading/re-scaling them to fit a standard pdf's A4 sized page for example and then save the resulting pdf file locally.

Can anyone help me out regarding this? As to how to proceed? Any complete samples are appreciated.